# Java: Can wildcard array type be used as both argument and return type?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

Consider, for example, a function that takes an ArrayList of String and splits it into String arrays, and returns an ArrayList of those new arrays:

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> splitListIntoArrays(ArrayList<String> list, int divisor) {
    ArrayList<String> listSplit = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        listSplit.add(list.get(i));
        if ((listSplit.size() + divisor) % divisor == 0 || i == (list.size() - 1)) {
        listOfArrays.add(listSplit.toArray(new String[listSplit.size()]));
        listSplit = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    return listOfArrays;
    }
```

Now, suppose I want to do the same thing, but for an ArrayList of Long:

```
public static ArrayList<Long[]> splitListIntoArrays(ArrayList<Long> list, int divisor) {
    ArrayList<Long> listSplit = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Long[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        listSplit.add(list.get(i));
        if ((listSplit.size() + divisor) % divisor == 0 || i == (list.size() - 1)) {
        listOfArrays.add(listSplit.toArray(new Long[listSplit.size()]));
        listSplit = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    return listOfArrays;
    }
```

Is there a best approach to this that might avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Defining a generic method seems the most natural approach:

```
  public static <T> List<T[]> splitListIntoArrays(List<T> list, int divisor)
  {
    ArrayList<T> listSplit = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<T[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        listSplit.add(list.get(i));
        if ((listSplit.size() + divisor) % divisor == 0 || i == (list.size() - 1))
        {
          listOfArrays.add(listSplit.toArray(new T[listSplit.size()]));
          listSplit = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    return listOfArrays;
  }
```

I replaced `ArrayList<T>` with `List<T>` interface just because it's more generic.

The code is nice but there's a problem: you can't create a generic array so this

```
new T[listSplit.size()]
```

is not valid Java code.

There are multiple solutions to the problems, many of them rely on reflection. The better and fastest solution would be to pass the class directly to the method, so that you can use reflection to instantiate the array:

```
  public static <T> List<T[]> splitListIntoArrays(List<T> list, int divisor, Class<T> clazz)
  {
    ArrayList<T> listSplit = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<T[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        listSplit.add(list.get(i));
        if ((listSplit.size() + divisor) % divisor == 0 || i == (list.size() - 1))
        {
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          T[] array = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, listSplit.size());

          listOfArrays.add(listSplit.toArray(array));
          listSplit = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    return listOfArrays;
  }
```

so that it now works:

```
  static void test()
    {
      List<String> test = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "barbaz");
      List<String[]> split = splitListIntoArrays(test, 2, String.class);
      split.forEach(s -> java.lang.System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));


      List<Long> test2 = Arrays.asList(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L);
      List<Long[]> split2 = splitListIntoArrays(test2, 2, Long.class);
      split2.forEach(s -> java.lang.System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));
    }
```

output:

```
[foo, bar]
[baz, foobar]
[barbaz]
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5]
```

Comment: Thanks for reading my question/code and for your great answer.  Follow-up question: Since the passed ArrayList seems to implicitly carry the type of objects in the list, why is it not possible to avoid passing the class (perhaps by calling getClass() on list.get(0), or something to that effect)??

Comment: Because the `List` is not effectively carrying anything, the type variable `T` is something that is used by the compiler to check the correctness of your code but it doesn't exist at runtime because Java uses type erasure: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html. That's why you must pass the `Class<T>`. There are solutions which are able to query at runtime the generic type of a field of a class but they're quite overkill for the problem.

Comment: @neex: You *can* use `list.get(0).get class()`, but then the caller has to guarantee that the first list element is non-null and has a runtime-type that's a supertype of any type that might be needed. (Consider a `List<Object>` whose first element is a string.) This is a counterintuitive requirement, and relates to things the caller shouldn't have to worry about. Far better to just pass in the class as an explicit argument.

Comment: It might be better to take `List<? extends T>`, to give the caller a bit more flexibility.